# What load signal there should be on the load?

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I built this bootstrap circuit to drive high-side MOSFET as it is seen in the book.

[image]

[image]

I also know that it is not the perfect solution to drive high-side switches. So when the switches are on, the bootstrap capacitor charges to Vs, when off, the gate voltage is 2Vs. Like in the picture(there is a small decrease from 20V because of the current inrush resistor series with diode):

[image]

But the load voltage is also an (11V) pulse, I don't think that is correct because how can the load work properly with a pulse? For example, load like the 10.8V dc motor. Shouldn't it be a constant dc? I want to know if this is the anticipated output or if am I doing wrong somewhere.

[image]

**I really appreciate any help, thank you.**

Comment: If you want the driver to act as a DC switch then bootstrapping is not what you want to do.

Comment: But what can I use instead? I do not want to use driver ICs. I want it to be simpler and cheaper.

Comment: This is a Q and A site and not a forum. If you want to ask that question then raise a brand new question.

Comment: make the pulse on 99% of the time and off 1%. Put a diode in reverse-parallel with the motor. Now your motor is running at 99% power and who cares about the last 1%?

Comment: @user253751, doesn't run the motor at 99% power cause any trouble with the motor?

Comment: no? motors are quite flexible devices. In fact 99% might be lower than necessary, you might even get away with 99.9% or 99.99%.

Answer (score 1):

> *But the load voltage is also an (11V) pulse, I don't think that is
> correct because how can the load work properly with a pulse? For
> example, load like the 10.8V dc motor. Shouldn't it be a constant dc?
> I want to know if this is the anticipated output or if am I doing
> wrong somewhere.*

If you want the driver to act as a DC switch then bootstrapping is not what you want to do. Bootstrapping is used in circuits that requires a load to be regularly switched; a DC system needs a different approach.

> *I really appreciate any help, thank you.*

Well, it's not good news but at least you are now aware that the bootstrapping approach is not going to be successful. Maybe consider a p-channel MOSFET as a high-side switch.

> *For example, load like the 10.8V dc motor. Shouldn't it be a constant
> dc? I want to know if this is the anticipated output or if am I doing
> wrong somewhere.*

DC motors are well-suited to being driven by a square wave as a means of speed control by altering the duty cycle of the input (switch control in your top diagram) but, if you are using a bootstrap circuit, you still need to avoid 100 % PWM because the bootstrap circuit fails.

Comment: yeah, thank you )) But I have read that generally n-channel is used as the high-side switch, isn't it right?

Comment: @Shamurov n-channel devices are usually better than p-channel devices in terms of the fine details of the specifications and, that is why they tend to be more used in high-side switches but, in doing so, bootstrapping is required or some form of signal isolation and a DC-to-DC converter. A p-channel MOSFET achieves a high-side function that can produce a continuous output without needing a bootstrap circuit or external power supplies but, like I said, they don't perform ultimately as well as an n-channel device. However, p-channel devices are perfectly fine in many high-side applications.

Comment: I know I asked a lot of questions but why does it fail?

Comment: If the output doesn't regularly drop to 0 volts for a short period of time, the bootstrap capacitor fails to be recharged and, after a short while of driving the gate of the upper MOSFET, the gate voltage dwindles until the upper MOSFET can no longer be activated properly. The bootstrap capacitor must be regularly recharged for the bootstrap circuit to work @Shamurov

Answer (score 1):

People use P-channel mosfets or PNP transistors as high side DC switches. They do not need bootstrapping to lift the voltage.

If there's a proper reason why you must have the shown N-channel mosfet as the high side switch either use bootstrapping and recharge the capacitor often enough to get the needed voltage lift above +Vs. That means pulses. Or insert an auxiliary power supply which generates high enough voltage. You may need 5 or 10 volts more than Vs. How many volts and how much current exactly - that must be calculated for your case separately. That supply can have floating output and you connect its minus output to +Vs.